%load_ext rpy2.ipython resulting in dead kernel
I am running a program in jupyter notebook. I have installed rpy2. When I try and rung the %load_ext rpy2.ipython command I get this error every time telling me the kernel has died and will automatically restart:
enter image description here
There is no additional error message.
I read a suggestion that I should try running it in the basic ipython console, but I receive the same error message that the kernal has died and will restart. Any suggestions? I have tried uninstalling then reinstalling rpy2 to no avail. Any help would be appreciated!
